# How to get the folder location on server with the domain name

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm working on a c# web application which is hosted on an server `192.168.X.Y`. In this application I'm accessing few documents which are inside a folder on a server `192.168.X.YYY\Folder`(I'm providing this info in the Web.Config file). But the actual path of `192.168.X.YYY\Folder` has a different name like `abc.Application.com\Application1\Folder`. How can I get this name in my c# application? Because I want to open the documents in this folder using google document viewer.

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

`Server.MapPath(".")`1 returns the current physical directory of the file is being executed
`Server.MapPath("..")` returns the parent directory

`Server.MapPath("~")` returns the physical path to the root of the application
`Server.MapPath("/")` returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Saumendra. I tried Server.MapPath("/"). But it showed me the location of my application on the local machine.

Comment: Please close this, if you it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I used `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` which served my purpose.